# How to access .env variabable in DTO files symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have DTO property like:

```
   /**
    * @Assert\Email
    * @Assert\Choice({"<a>","<b>","<c>","..."})
    * @JMS\Type("string")
    * @var string $email
    */
   public $email;
```

I want to use few **.env** variables instead of the values inside the `@Assert\Choice`

Is it possible to do this? and how?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use a custom validator for this, and inject the needed variables?